# New blank window is not opening through javascript

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, firefox

Issue is only for firefox android but other browser on android works fine. Such as Chrome or Opera or Edge etc...

I am building a web app where I need to open blank tab for redirect its working on desktop but not in android.

```
    /**
     * New Window
     */
    const newWindow: any = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
    /**
     * Loading Text
     */
    const textNode: any = newWindow.document.createElement('h1');
    textNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Loading ...'));
    newWindow.document.body.appendChild(textNode);
```

When the open parameter is empty it should open blank tab but instead its opening the current location.
When put 'about:blank" in open parameter, it open blank page but the createNode function & other codes are not running.

Comment: empty parameter open current location which should not be. so I put `about:blank` & now its open empty page but `createElement` & other codes does no run

Comment: I just want to open a blank page & redirect the user. now this code works fine in all browser but only in android firefox has some issue. no problem with desktop firefox

Comment: Normal website no PWA

Comment: I don't experience the same issue - how is that code being executed? through an event handler?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using react js. & On Click Event it trigger

Comment: well, your issue does not exist for me when using `window.open('', '_blank')` - so use that rather than what you have in the question - that doesn't work - also, I don't use `_blank` I use `someRandomWindowName` ... as per recommendations to avoid using `_blank`

Comment: when I use `window.open('', 'win')` its loading current url again & not empty window. just now I tried again

Comment: the only time I get that is when I execute window.open in code that is NOT the result of a user action - but, you're doing it in an on click handler - like I do in [this very simple proof of concept I created just for you](https://icanhazcode.com/test.html)

Comment: thank you for the snippet. looks like its working but the same thing is not working in my code. I have to debug it. Can you please tell me what is purpose of `window.opener`

Comment: Oh, I had that there when I was "blindly" opening the window without being a response to user input ... see, when you do that, the new tab (with the current page as you are aware) will open a new tab (with the current page), which opens a new tab ... which opens a new tab - you get the picture :p checking if `wndow.opener` is falsey prevents that :p ... fortunately firefox android always asked before it opened the new tab - that's how I could replicate your issue - by opening a new window outside of a click event handler

Comment: in other words, it's not important and removed now

Comment: I'd be interested to know why your code works different though :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I have found the RCA. Its firefox issue or policy that prevent popup window or tab to open or redirect different url.

Comment: Error code is 0x80004005